# Angular Directives how to use for repeating data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I am doing a webservice call returning address data i.e. Address Line 1-10 twice.

My view looks something like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="address in search.result.addresses">
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine1}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine2}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine3}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine4}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine5}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine6}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine7}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine8}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.address.addressLine9}}</strong>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="address in search.result.addresses">
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine1}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine2}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine3}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine4}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine5}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine6}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine7}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine8}}</strong>
  <strong>{{ address.OtherAddress.addressLine9}}</strong>
</div>
```

And this works fine, but doesn't seem very angular, should I be creating a directive to handle this which maybe could work for both lists ?

Comment: Can you rewrite a web-service so it'll return both address.address and address.OtherAddress as arrays instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpG5n4ZTveMaGEPKVzJ5?p=preview) to demonstrate a basic directive.

Usage:

```
<div ng-repeat="address in Addresses">
  <address-list address=address.address></address-list>
  <address-list address=address.otherAddress></address-list>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('addressList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      address: '=address'
    },
    templateUrl: 'addressList.html'
  };
});
```

addressList.html:

```
<strong>{{ address.addressLine1}}</strong>
<strong>{{ address.addressLine2}}</strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. Instead of seaparating `addressLine1, addressLine2, ...`, you can make the service return an array which has all the address lines.

```
<div ng-repeat="address in search.result.addresses">
    <div ng-repeat="addressLine in address.address">
       <strong>{{ addressLine }}</strong>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="address in search.result.addresses">
    <div ng-repeat="addressLine in address.OtherAddress">
       <strong>{{ addressLine }}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```